# Unexpected value present in C array after sorting - Can anyone explain why?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

This is a simple way of sorting an array in ascending order in C. but after sorting when i print the array it comes as 1 5 11 14 15 **33**. Can someone explain me where the 33 comes from since i have not initialized 33 in my array

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int arr [6]={11,1,5,125,15,14};
int i, j, k, temp;

for (i=0; i<6; i++){
  for(j=i+1; j<7; j++){
    if (arr[i]>arr[j]){
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j]=temp;
    }
  }
}

for (k=0; k<6; k++){
    printf("%d ", arr[k]);
}
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop accesses index 6 of the array which is out of bounds.

Comment: `for(j=i+1; j<7; j++)` accesses the array out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defined indices of an array declared `int arr[6]` are 0 to 5, inclusive. The loop `for(j=i+1; j<7; j++)` lets `j` go to 6, and the program uses `j` to index the array.

So the program accesses `arr` out of bounds, and the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

the algorithm you used to sort the integer array is called **Selection Sort** and it usually needs two for loops where the inner for loop is nested inside the outer for loop but the outer loop starts from index **0** while the inner loop starts from index **1**, the maximum length for both loops must be the same, which means your inner loop needs to have **j<6** instead of **j<7** which is the one causing a bug in your program as the outer loop has **i<6**. The length needs to be the same for the inner and outer loop. Check the code below on how you can resolve that issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


 int main()
    {
        int arr [6]={11,1,5,125,15,14};
        int i, j, k, temp;

        for (i=0; i<6; i++){
            for(j=i+1; j<6; j++){
                if (arr[i]>arr[j]){
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (k=0; k<6; k++){
            printf("%d ", arr[k]);
        }
        //outputs 1 5 11 14 15 125 
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it is selection sort and not bubble sort?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, it's the selection sort where the outer loop starts at index 0 then the inner loop starts at index 1 then we swap the elements after comparing inside the loop.

Comment: If you look at the code in the Wikipedia article on [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), you'll see that there's only one swap per cycle of the outer loop (no swapping operation in the inner loop; just recording an index value to use when the inner loop completes).  The article on [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) shows possible swapping on each cycle of the inner loop, as in this code.  You can look at [Insertion Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I have reviewed  each of the articles and learnt that the bubble sort has a do while loop in it's body and the selection sort looks mic similar to my code only that it uses a variable called Min to compare elements